# Image header with rotativa and null layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I have recently started using Rotativa and it's amazing, but today, i try to add a header to my pdf, it works without problems, but the header is rendered using the `_layout.cshtml` and when I try to remove it using `Layout = null` or rendering the header as `PartialView` instead of `View` it just show a empty page.

This is how i'm working

```
public ActionResult Print(string CodigoDelfos, int Revision, string Versiones)
{
    //Create the url for the header (Test action)
    UriBuilder u = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    {
        Path = Url.Action("Test", "Home", null),
        Query = null
    };

    //Format the header to read Test.cshtml file
    string t = string.Format("--header-html {0}", u.Uri.ToString());

    //The action i'll use to create the pdf        
    return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf(nameof(ImprimirDetalleDistribucion), new
    {
        CodigoDelfos,
        Revision,
        Versiones
    })
    {
        CustomSwitches = t
    };
}
```

Then the `Test.cshtml` file

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/CabeceraGarantizados.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
```

Here it work fine if i render it as `View()` (renders with deffault layout) but if i do it as `PartialView()` the pdf result is `blank` in the same way as if I use `Layout = null`

Why can this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Rotary needs the file to have the `DOCTYPE` defined

The solution was just add `DOCTYPE`

Test.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="container">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/CabeceraGarantizados.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch.  This is easy to miss and there are no exceptions thrown with the DOCTYPE is left off.